# XJC error while processing NIEM 3.0 schemas

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, xsd-validation, xjc

**XJC error while processing NIEM 3.0 schemas**

I am running a xjc.exe specifying the NIEM schema folder. It have a number of xsds and some conflict is happening.

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] 'href' is already defined
  line 16 of file:/C:/Users/xxxx/xx/Projects/xxxx/NIEM/niem/external/have/1.0/xlinks.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 14 of file:/C:/Users/xxxx/xx/Projects/xxxx/niem/external/ogc/xlink/1.0.0/xlinks.xsd
```